# How do I access the object in manifest.json in my Chrome app?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

I'm not seeing a way to get the information that's in my manifest.json, at runtime. Is it not accessible within the app, or am I overlooking it somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `chrome.runtime.getManifest()`, which returns an object representing the manifest.